# Square root and Looping on Standard Deviation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, math

I'm trying to get the difference of each members versus the mean (given mean = 4.5 for example) and the square root of the result of these two using each loop. Following the steps on this [link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html), what I did was. The `total = square root of (array[0] - average) + square root of (array[1] - average) + ...`

```
array = [some values here]
average = 4.5           #as example to make the code shorter
squaredifference = 0
#Loop through the array, accumulate the total of the 
#difference of num and average and of the square root of that result
array.each { |num| squaredifference += Math::sqrt(num - average) } 
puts squaredifference
```

My error was

```
Math::DomainError: NumericalNumerical argument is out of domain - "sqrt"
from (irb):5:in `sqrt'
from (irb):5:in `block in irb_binding'
from (irb):5:in `each'
from (irb):5
from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are giving `Math::sqrt` a negative number as argument.

To calculate the difference of `num` and `average`, use its absolute value:

```
Math::sqrt((num - average).abs)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that you are attempting to compute the square root of a negative number, it is that you should be calculating the *square* of that number.  You want:

```
squared_difference += (num - average)**2
```

Once you have the sum of all squared deviations from the mean, you can calculate the population variance:

```
variance = squared_difference/n
```

where `n` is the size of the population. The standard deviation is simply the square root of the variance:

```
standard_deviation = Math::sqrt(variance)
```

If you are calculating the variance of a *sample* (rather than a population) of size `n`, use the formula:

```
variance = squared_difference/(n-1)
```

to obtain an unbiased estimator of the variance. Again, the standard deviation is the square root of the variance.